# small suspicion in "Baby" Rudin: Exact form is closed

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Section 10.34 of Baby Rudin is saying that exact forms are closed:

> Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form in an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If there is a $(k-1)$-form $\lambda$ in $E$ such that $\omega = d\lambda$, then $\omega$ is said to be *exact* in $E$.
>
> If $\omega$ is of class $C'$ and $d\omega =0$, then $\omega$ is said to be *closed*.
>
> Theorem 10.20(b) shows that every exact form of class $C'$ is closed.

I am a bit suspicious of the last sentence. If $\omega$ is exact and of class $C'$, then there exist a $(k-1)$-form $\lambda$ such that $\omega =d\lambda$. But to use Theorem 10.20(b) to deduce that $d\omega=0$, we need that $\lambda$ is of class $C''$.

So I let $\lambda = \sum_I b_I (x) dx_I $, so that $d\lambda = \sum_I \sum_i (D_i b_I )(x) dx_i \wedge dx_I $ is of class $C'$.

To deduce that $b_I$'s are of class $C''$, we need $(D_i b_I )$'s are of class $C'$, but I am not able to get this because we only have the 'sums' which have same $dx_i \wedge dx_I$ are of class $C'$.

Since my explanation is not clear, let me give you an example. ($k=2$)

Let $\lambda = a(x,y,z)dx +b(x,y,z)dy + c(x,y,z) dz$

We want to show that if $\omega = d\lambda$ is of class $C'$, $d^2 \lambda =0$. We have that

\begin{equation}
\omega = d\lambda = \left ( \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} \right ) dx \wedge dy + \left ( \frac{\partial b}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial y} \right ) dy \wedge dz + \left ( \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \right ) dz \wedge dx 
\end{equation}
is of class $C'$. If $a, b, c$ are of class $C''$, (which means $\lambda$ is of class $C''$) we easily obtain (by calculation or using theorem 10.20(b)) $d^2 \lambda =0$.

But, I think $ \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial b}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial a}{\partial z}$ can be of class $C'$ without $a, b, c$ being of class $C''$, and so $d^2 \lambda$ might not be equal to $0$.

Lastly, here are some definitions and theorems in Rudin.

Theorem 10.20(b) of Baby Rudin:

> If ($k$-form) $\omega$ is of class $C''$ in $E$, then $d^2 \omega =0$.

Definition of $k$-forms:

> $k$-form in $E$ is a function $\omega = \sum a_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(x ) dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}$, which assigns to each $k$-surface $\Phi$ in $E$ a number $\int_{\Phi} \omega = \int_{D} \sum a_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(\Phi (u) ) \frac{\partial (x_{i_1} , \cdots , x_{i_k} )}{\partial (u_1 , \cdots , u_k)} du$ where $D$ is parameter domain of $\Phi$.
>
> $\omega$ is said to be of class $C'$ (or $C''$) if $a_{i_1 \cdots i_k}$s are all of class $C'$ (or $C''$).

But to be more precise, I think $\omega$ should said to be of class $C'$ (or $C''$) if $b_I$, which is summation of $a_{i_1 \cdots i_k }$ where $ \{ i_1 , \cdots , i_k \} = I $, are of class $C'$ (or $C''$).

Thanks you for reading my question. I hope to see some answers here.

And one more small question: I think these kind of suspicion are really small thing, and sometimes I think these thoughts make me waste time. Should I just ignore these small suspicions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You raise a valid point. This, among other reasons, is one reason it's customary to work with smooth differential forms most of the time.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment. But I'm still confused, since we still can't deduce $\omega$ is closed even though it is exact form of class $C^{\infty}$. Or, do you mean by "to work with smooth differential forms" to use 'there exist smooth $\lambda$ with $\omega = d\lambda$' as a definition of exact form $\omega$?

Comment: Sure you can. If you had assumed all forms were $C''$, the proof would have worked fine, as you already observed.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you for spending time for this small question :)

Comment: Good for you for noticing the sloppiness. Do you think you can find an example where it fails as stated? I thought about it a little bit and the standard examples I know don't work.

Comment: @TedShifrin I also tried it, but failed. I just thought it could be true and there's a clever proof of it. It will be great if there's a counterexamples though..