# Theorem 10.20 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I have a question about the proof of Rudin Theorem 10.20

> **Theorem 10.20**
>
> (a)If $\omega, \lambda $ are $k-$ and $m-$ forms, respectively of class $C^{1}$ in $E$, then $$d(\omega \land \lambda)=(d\omega)\land \lambda + (-1)^{k}\omega \land d\lambda$$
>
> (b) If $\omega$ is of class $C^{1}$, then $d^{2} \omega=0$

I have two questions regarding the proof

First, $\omega=\sum b_{I}(x)dx_{I}$ and $\lambda=\sum c_{J}(x)dx_{J}$, but the proof said (a) follows if (a) is proved for the special case $\omega=fdx_{I}$ and $\lambda=gdx_{J}$, Why?

Second, the proof said $d(dx_{I})=0$ since $d\omega=\sum db_{I} \land dx_{I}$, I think if we let $\omega=dx_{I}$, by this definition, we get $d(dx_{I})=0\land dx_{I}$ , is $0\land dx_{I}=0$? if so, how to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As we discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371979/small-suspicion-in-baby-rudin-exact-form-is-closed), part (b) seems to be a mistake on Rudin's part. You need to assume $\omega$ is $C^2$, and then you will need to use equality of mixed second partial derivatives.